# How can there be non-computably enumerable sets in a computably enumerable degree?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability, turing-machines

I was just reading up about turing degrees and the part marked in red confused me:

[Screnshot of book page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rc8o.png)

If there was a non computably enumerable turing machine that could be computed given the computably enumerable set as an oracle - shouldn't it also be possible to simply c.e. this second set in the first turing machine instead and use it? And wouldn't that make the first set also computably enemerable?

Probably I'm messing something up here, but I really can't seem to figure it out.
I'd be really thankful if anyone could tell me, what I'm getting wrong here.
Thank you in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: Good question - this is quite subtle. Computable enumerability is weaker than computability! In particular if a set is CE that doesn't mean there's a TM that's an oracle for that set. For an example, take a CE but not computable set (eg the set of programs that halt). Its complement is in the same equivalence class, but the complement cannot be CE! (Can you work out the details?)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thank you - now it makes sense! The example with the halting problem really clarified things :)